# Batch process directory of JSON files using BASH / scripting language /?

Tags: json, bash

I have a directory that contains many sub-directories and dozens of JSON files.  At this point when I need to change a particular key's value it is very time consuming.  If i wanted to say change the string value of a given key on all of these files at once, could this be done in BASH?  If not a shell script, than in python, ruby, or some scripting language?  Furthermore, are there any pre-existing tools for doing batch edits such as this?

Answer (score 1):

Bash is just not suitable to edit JSONs - chances are you'll need to use regexes, and using regexes for JSON is silly (especially given that Bash regexes are very limited). Same goes for tools such as sed or awk. Python, Ruby and Perl can extract information and edit JSON just fine, but using them with command line for manual one-shot editing is pretty ineffective (much less than Bash, though).

I believe what you're looking for is a command line utility [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) that was made just for the purpose you've described. Check out [its tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/).